# Как ограничить выбор radiobutton, принадлежащих разным группам?

Tags: javascript, input, radio, radiobutton

У меня есть три группы radiobutton

```
<input id="1" name="A" type="radio" /> 
<input id="2" name="A" type="radio" /> 

<input id="3" name="B" type="radio" /> 
<input id="4" name="B" type="radio" /> 

<input id="5" name="C" type="radio" /> 
<input id="6" name="C" type="radio" />
```

Мне необходимо сделать так (функция в javascript), чтобы при выборе ЛЮБОГО ОДНОГО radiobutton с любым id из любой группы, выбрать radio из других групп было сразу же нельзя. То есть при выборе id=1, все остальные варианты из других групп name должны быть недоступны для выбора.

Сейчас статус checked можно присвоить одновременно трем переменным - по одной из каждой группы (A, B, C), что не есть правильно. Скрипт у меня конечно берет последнее выбранное значение и передает его правильно при нажатии кнопки отправить. Но смущает визуальная составляющая. Не хочется путать посетителя сайта.
Есть идеи?
Вот текущий код передачи имени группы:

```
    function getRadioValue(radioboxGroupName)
{
    group=document.getElementsByName(radioboxGroupName);
    for (x=0;x<group.length;x++)
    {
        if (group[x].checked)
        {
            return (group[x].id);
        }
    }
    return (false);
}
```

Как его дополнить, чтобы ограничить выбор остальных radio, после выбора ОДНОГО любого radiobutton?

PS вариант сделать одну группу не предлагать. На то есть причины.
Спасибо!!!!

Comment: "выбрать radio из других групп было сразу же нельзя" - я ничего не понял

Comment: то есть получается, что человек единожды кликнув в группу уже не сможет никак изменить свой выбор?

Comment: не ясно зачем вам 3 группы, если выбирается одно значение. оставьте одну группу. отправлять если что можно вообще хидден поле, а не радио

Comment: Кнопку RESET никто не отменял. Мне надо чтобы за 1 раз можно было выбрать только 1 вариант из всех предложенных.

Comment: Teran - для вас специально последняя строка написана. Не могу я одну группу сделать. Если бы мог я бы тут не задавал этот вопрос - потому что это самое простое и банальное решение, не требующее подсказок ))

Comment: может ваши "не предлагать" и "причины" просто упираются в кругозор и опыт, и вы начинаете городить что-то, где решение может оказаться более простым?

Answer (score 2):

Перебрать список всех радио, дать `disabled="true"` всему, чей `name` не совпадает с выбранным:

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.js-radio');
// Если нельзя добавить класс, ...All('[name="A"], [name="B"], [name="C"]');

for (let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
  radio[i].addEventListener('change', disable_others);
}

function disable_others() {
  for (let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    radio[i].disabled = radio[i].name != this.name;
  }
  
  console.log('Выбрано:', this.id); // А числовые id точно нужны?
}
```

```html
<input class="js-radio" id="1" name="A" type="radio" /> 
<input class="js-radio" id="2" name="A" type="radio" /> 

<input class="js-radio" id="3" name="B" type="radio" /> 
<input class="js-radio" id="4" name="B" type="radio" /> 

<input class="js-radio" id="5" name="C" type="radio" /> 
<input class="js-radio" id="6" name="C" type="radio" />
```

Comment: "все остальные варианты из других групп name должны быть недоступны для выбора", а не все оставшиеся

Comment: @GGO упс, исправлено.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME - id взял просто для примера чтобы не запутаться. В оригинале там идут обычные уникальные записи типа id=time id=time2 id=time3 и тд